# How to execute SSH Android cmd command from vb.net

Tags: android, vb.net

I am trying to send ssh command from VB.NET to my Android TV box to reboot it.

I tried this code but nothing happened, ssh session opened but the cmd not execute

```
    Dim connInfo As New Renci.SshNet.PasswordConnectionInfo("ip address", "port", "username", "password")
    Dim sshClient As New Renci.SshNet.SshClient(connInfo)
    'Need to hold the command'
    Dim cmd As Renci.SshNet.SshCommand
    Using sshClient
        sshClient.Connect()
        cmd = sshClient.RunCommand("reboot")
        sshClient.Disconnect()
    End Using
```

When I start the App and pause it i found in the debug stopped in

```
     cmd = sshClient.RunCommand("reboot")
```

and the Android TV box not rebooted!

Any Idea for my case

And Thanks for all

Comment: I forgot to say I am using Renci SSHNET  Library..but when I am access ssh from my putty I can access and make command but from VB.NET app I couldn't

Comment: Any Idea about it please?